# How to get Chatter daily digest email for All Company Feed?

Tags: chatter

I can only subscribe to daily digest email for Chatter groups I am a member of.

How to get Chatter daily digests for **All Company Feed**?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is currently not available. The way the current daily digest works is that you only see all items you're following.

Depending on the size of your data, you may be able to get away with a scheduled Apex job that  does a query and then emails all of the information to you.

Since this is a new feature request, you might want to post it on the [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaHome).

Comment: There's [this older labs app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003GKSLEA4&tab=r) that approached the scheduled apex job.  I took it private a while back, you'll want to make sure it uses the right data model, etc.  You should be able to test in a dev edition.